Is this SRAM X7 bent?
Lower jockey wheel seems to not be in line with upper so wondering if if was in an accident or bent somehow. If so, anything likely needed besides a new derailleur?


Yes.
Looks like the bottom of the derailleur cage is kicked outboard by some amount.  That's relatively unusual, normally they get pushed in toward the centerline.
If the bike is shifting okay, then consider leaving it as-is.  Attempting an un-bend can make things worse given that aluminium doesn't like to un-bend in the same way steel can.
If your shifting is slow, clacky, or otherwise unreliable then try bending the derailleur back to original shape.   Use a set of waterpump pliers to hold the top of the cage still and push the bottom part with your hand.  Avoid just pushing the cage around because all the bending will be spread through the derailleur's parallelogram movement.
If it breaks on unbending, it was already weak and you needed a new one anyway.

Separately, try and think back to what caused this.  Did you get a rock or stick or long grass jammed in the transmission somewhere?
Another possibility is the entire derailleur is mounted to the hanger, which has bent.  Replacement hangers are available, but are generally unique to the brand and often to the specific model of frame.  Again, unbending steel is more successful than aluminium.
Good luck!
